# Cannot get gpg key id to upload to launchpad

Tags: ssh, gnupg, launchpad

Trying to set up packaging environment for [launchpad](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html) but cannot send the key to keyserver because it doesn't show me the key id like it shows in the guide and cannot find it.
Any ideeas how to find the key id which I need to send?

In the guide, the example shows the following:

> pub   4096R/43CDE61D 2010-12-06
>         Key fingerprint = 5C28 0144 FB08 91C0 2CF3  37AC 6F0B F90F 43CD E61D
>   uid                  Daniel Holbach dh@mailempfang.de\
>   sub   4096R/51FBE68C 2010-12-06

Where the key is 43CDE61D.

My key is:

> pub   rsa3072 2019-02-25 [SC] [expiră: 2021-02-24]
>         854A1142327A80B6FBFA9C1CF50AC356DCB3BE7F
>   uid           [ supremă] Real name mail@gmail.com
>   sub   rsa3072 2019-02-25 [E] [expiră: 2021-02-24]

Trying either rsa3072 or 3072 results in the following error:
"It is not a key ID"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
```

to obtain full information including key ID.

See [this link for more information about gpg keys](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key).